# Java method for empty input

Tags: java, methods, java-7

I have a java method which is supposed to check 20 inputs parameters for empty and return a message

Example:

```
public String CheckEmpty(String a,String b,String c, String d,String e, String f, String g, String i,String j, String k,.....) {
    String str="";
    if(a.isEmpty()){
        str= "a is empty";
    }
    if(b.isEmpty()){
        str= "b is empty";
    }
    return str;
}
```

I need to check for the **if condition** for all inputs? there are around 20 inputs or is there any efficient way of doing the same check in java ?

Please advise.

Comment: The Strings a,b,c,d etc are coming in request parameters individually.

Comment: Right and then cylcle through all items in a for-loop. By this the function does not even need to know, how many parameters you passed. Also right now you should think about the return value. In your way if a and b are empty the function will only return "b is empty" ...

Comment: @user3492471 then what's the problem of constructing an array from those strings?

Comment: Imho better solution is not to pass 20 arguments to a method but varargs, or maybe array of strings? The less arguments a method has the better and easier to read :)

Comment: Also since the strings are coming in request parameters individually, why don't you call the same method on them?

Answer (score 7):

It's better to use variable arguments like this:

```
public String checkEmtpy(String... args) {
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        if(args[i].isEmpty()) {
            return ((char)('a'+i))+" is empty";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

For example, `checkEmtpy("aaa", "b", "", "ddd")` returns `c is empty`.

Comment: You were a bit faster than me :), btw the best solution for this problem.

Comment: But what happens if you pass checkEmpty("aaa", "", "cc", ""). You will only return "b is empty" even though the last parameter is empty too. It probably depends on what needs to be achieved by the return value ...

Comment: It is better to return a map with parameters and related messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map(<String>, <String>)` as parameter, then do the checks in a loop.

The keys of the map would be the variable names, the values of the map would be the values that you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String CheckEmpty(List<String> argumentList) {
    for(Iterator<String> i = argumentList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String item = i.next();
        System.out.println(item);
    }
        return item;
}
```

Comment: Why iterator? `for( : )` is shorter. Why does method returns nothing?

Comment: @cybersoft, it shows an approach how to handle multiple arguments using list, returning something was not the main purpose.

Answer (score -1):

1. Take input parameters as a string array
2. Then loop through it and check for each element's **boolean representation**

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<20;i++)  
   {  
       if(null == stringInputArray[i])  
       {
       //Using **i** you can take the current empty element's index and 
         do your stuff here...
       }  
   }
   ```

**UPDATE:**

Change code to check whether element is null.

Comment: `Boolean.valueOf("asd")` also returns false. [see java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: Sorry :(. and thanks also. changed code to use null check instead.